# What could make `>` silently fail in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash

I ran this command:

```
python ./manage.py dumpdata partyapp.InvitationTemplate > partyapp_dump.json
```

To dump data into the `partyapp_dump.json` file. But all the data just gets printed on the screen and an empty `partyapp_dump.json` file is created.

Why could this happen? I tested `ls > partyapp_dump.json` and that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

With **>** you only redirect the standard output.
Try **2>** instead to redirect the error output. Use **&>** to redirect both.

Comment: FYI, `&>` will only work in Bash 4.0 and iirc recent versions of zsh. For a more portable solution, `foo > bar 2&>1`. Reference: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/014

Comment: @Rein Henrichs: That's 2>&1, not 2&>1

Comment: I remember it with a pneumonic(?) from programming: '2', to('>') the Location('&') Of '1'

Comment: @hometoast: You mean mnemonic? :) Pneumonic means lung...

Answer (score 22):

Your python app must be writing it's output to the STDERR output channel instead of the normal STDOUT. Using the shell construct `>` only catches and redirects data written to the output channel, but there are actually several other channels that can be printed to, the most common being the second one, usually used for errors.

You can try trapping STDERR (2nd channel) as well like this:

```
python ./manage.py dumpdata partyapp.InvitationTemplate > partyapp_dump.json 2>&1
```

The `2>&1` construct connects the output stream for errors to normal output channel. *It is unusual for a program to generate output that you would want to capture on the error channel; usually that would be reserved for debug information not application data. Please **use this script with some caution** since it is behaving in a non-standard way.*

You could also dump the output and error channels to different files like this:

```
python ./manage.py dumpdata partyapp.InvitationTemplate > partyapp_dump.json 2> error_output.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the already suggested stderr vs stdout output explanation, your application might simply ignore both of these streams and explicitly open "/dev/tty" for its output.

Answer (score 1):

If the `noclobber` bash option is set, then > redirection will fail (albeit not silently) if the destination file already exists.

For better portability, use `cmd >| file` to force overwriting any existing file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are lost you can always try to run it with strace to see what processes are doing:

```
strace -f command
```

Comment: True answer, but not particularly relevant. If the guy didn't now about managing the error stream I don't think he's going to know what to do with the output of an `strace`.